# VBA - open corrupted file - excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have some files that when I manually try to open them come up with the below message:

Excel found unreadable content in `***.xlsx` . Do you want to recover the contents of the workbook?

When I click YES it shows me the below:

> Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.
>   Removed Feature: Data validation from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

And then I can manually save it, replace it, and the file thereafter opens normally with no errors.

Now my problem is, that I want to do the same with a VBA code. 
I prepared the below and there is no luck. It comes with 1004 error:

```
Sub letshope()


WithApplication
.DisplayAlerts=False
.ScreenUpdating=False
.EnableEvents=False
.AskToUpdateLinks=False
EndWith

Set wb =Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
"\\folder\***.xlsx", _
UpdateLinks:=0,Password:="password", _
IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, _
CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)


EndSub
```

Unfortunately everybody on the web suggests that with the `CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile` part all corrupted files open.
This is not the case.

Anyone who might have any kind of idea please?
It is a painful process opening them manually, saving them etc.

Once I manually open them and press to recover they all come up with the same error:

> error067760_07.xml
>
> ```
> Errors were detected in file 'XXXX.xlsx'</summary>
> -<removedFeatures summary="Following is a list of removed features:">
> <removedFeature>Removed Feature: Data validation from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedFeature></removedFeatures></recoveryLog>
> ```

Comment: I think the first thing that should be addressed is **how/why you're corrupting *so many* files** that you want to automate repair?  This is not something that should be automated anyhow since file corruption is, by definition, unpredictable and therefore can't and shouldn't be automated.  Have you removed & reinstalled Office?  It sounds like you need to have a separate install for working files or else you're going to keep having problems.

Comment: The second thing is that sometimes Excel says it repaired a file but then if you open it, it is still corrupt. I personally would never trust Excel on repairing files correctly. Many files will just stay corrupt. Also for huge Excel files with many data I got the best results not using the xlsx format but instead using the binary xlsb format, which seems to be much more stable.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what causes the corrupted files. They are all populated by a certain macro. This macro populates 2 files for each customer. File A and B. The A and B are then examined by different teams. Once they examine them, they save them and a reviewer is checking then A and B. All checks and examinations are manual without any macros.

95% of the times the corrupted file will be the B one. A is rarely corrupted.

Finally, once excel manually opens the corrupted file and resave it then the file is OK. No more corrupted...

Comment: so as a process I have a macro that opens A and B and check specific cells, then saves them to another list, compares and closes files. 
This is where I struggle as mosto of the Bs are corrupted every day....So the question is why doent work the CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile ?

Comment: @Yan_A don't bother yourself asking why `CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile` does not work. Ask yourself why your files get corrupted at all and solve this instead! I suggest try using the binary xlsb format instead of xlsx, and then see if they still get corrupted. If yes check your hard disk and memory. File recovery should always be done by hand, because you never know what you get. Something was corrupted does always mean that some information might got lost and you don't know which. So you should validate recovered data against a backup.

Comment: I followed your advice and i finally came up with the reason of the corrupted files. Some users were copying and pasting data from one file to another that contained data validation. So in the end I do not have any corrupted files again. Still no sollution how to open the corrupted ones but happy end afterall.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` just after function starts. And Set `Application.DisplayAlerts=True` just before function End.

The idea behind setting `Application.DisplayAlert` is bypassing any alert which is coming while working on excel.

NOTE: This is an application level setting, so resetting these option to their default values will be important thing or else no alerts will be seen when opening the excel(without programming).

```
Sub letshope()


With Application
.DisplayAlerts=False
.ScreenUpdating=False
.EnableEvents=False
.AskToUpdateLinks=False
End With

Set wb =Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
"\\folder\***.xlsx", _
UpdateLinks:=0,Password:="password", _
IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, _
CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)


With Application
.DisplayAlerts=True
.ScreenUpdating=True
.EnableEvents=True
.AskToUpdateLinks=True
End With


EndSub
```

'

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, but this work to me:

```
IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlExtractData
```